# WebLogic 14c compatibility with ORDS

Tags: database, weblogic, oracle-rest-data-services

I want to install WebLogic 14c. but I dnt know which ORDS version is compatible with WebLogic 14c.

kindly anyone help regarding compatibility of WebLogic 14-c to ORDS

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Support, it appears that the last version of ORDS (21.1.1) only supports WLS 12.2.1, 12.1.1 and 10.3.0

Comment: ORDS 21.1 does support Weblogic 14c: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.1/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#GUID-04A65471-5D4E-4C48-9054-51D8A894700B

Answer (score 0):

ORDS 21.4 (the current latest) does support WebLogic 14c: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.4/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#GUID-57B22E09-081E-4326-A9D5-61635B518931

```
Oracle REST Data Services supports the following Java EE application servers:

Application Server          Supported Release
---------------------------------------------------
Oracle WebLogic Server      12c Release 2 (from version 12.2.1.3 and later) and 14c Release and later

Apache Tomcat               Release 8.5.x through Release 9.0.x
```